# For Crestron/Extron, is there any framework in Java Lua D language?

Tags: java, lua, d, ada

Is there any framework to quickly build staffs with crestron/extron/axix processors via Java or Lua or D language or Ada.

Example:

- [DiN AP2](http://www.crestron.com/downloads/application_diagrams/182/din-ap2_exampleapplication.pdf)
- [DIN AP2 details](http://catalogs.infocommiq.com/AVCat/images/documents/pdfs/DIN-AP2%20Spec%20Sheet.pdf)
- [Fast development pdf](http://www.crestron.com/downloads/pdf/product_brochures/systembuilder_brochure.pdf)
- [Gui and builder, but not open source](http://www.crestron.com/downloads/pdf/spec_sheets/commercial_and_residential/sw-sb.pdf)

Note: They are always running (never almost goes down), allow to use in touch screen, automation, car embed, home embed, and more or less about SPEED. Just press the physical button and start all the magic, the most accurate real time hardware implementation

Follow up:

- I ask myself what is crestron? Seeing is believing this explains the visual features: http://www.crestron.com/interactive_automation_demo/corporate_enterprise_boardroom/
- I ask myself what is extron? google answer it nicely

Comment: I worked with someone who used to confuse stuff with staff.  He wrote a couple of classic emails. After work drinks party; "I came this morning and found staff all over the place", and another "Do anyone know of any old staff we can get rid of" ;)

Comment: Yes or no. Reliability comes from experiment and experience and years of analyze. Those equipment should not exist, if there isn't any cause. Many experts seems to underestimate such (we are all intelligent), but in reality or in practical life they still make very common sense of developing staff faster/quickly and be most productive.

Comment: The question is asking how to "build staff with ... processors" I assume you are not planing to create robot staff using these processors but its not clear to me what you are asking.

Comment: Have you asked the manufacturers of these processors this question. They would be the best people to help you. If they don't know the best way to use these processors, it unlikely anyone else will.

Comment: Actually i bought it from third hand market. Where i dont have manufacturers support, but i can do it myself too. What i thought is, i must not be alone person who is looking for such, and building some mockups manually instead of having bunch of tools to build the same way first hand users build. So i asked here, if somebody knew the answer as alternative.

Comment: There is a development environment platform but it comes from crestron as well. I doubt there are any free/open source frameworks. http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=crestron+development

Comment: Thanks, this link tools i was looking as free/open source frameworks: http://www.crestron.com/resources/product_and_programming_resources/catalogs_and_brochures/online_catalog/default.asp?jump=1&model=SW-SB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crestron is a proprietary automation system that uses their own SIMPL Windows programming environment to program the control system.  This has the capacity for including code written in SIMPL+, which is a *very* primitive procedural language with C like structure but no dynamic memory control.  The touch screens are programmed with VTPro-E, which is a simple graphics drawing program with limited animation and control capabilities that ties into the SIMPL program via 'joins' (similar to memory pointers).  This software is only available to authorised Crestron dealers.

There is no way to extend these environments with third party software without emulating the SIMPL/VT-ProE environment entirely.

Their new environment is supposed to also be programmable in C# - this has not yet been released though.

Extron make primarily video/audio switching hardware, and have some specific accessories designed to interface directly to their switching hardware.  I doubt there is a way to hook into that either.

[AMX](http://www.amx.com/) make products similar to Crestron.  The major difference is that they use a version of Java to program their system, so this might be something you could look into.

Bear in mind that all these systems are significantly expensive, and the Crestron and AMX systems require dedicated processors that then control the hardware IO modules and touchscreens that you use them with; a small system of control hardware can easily run $10k or more before you even look at programming time.

Comment: walsh: Yes you are correct. I have worked with Crestron/Extron processor. AMX i have also seen, and i know they are expensive. So thats they reason i was buying it from third hand market. The beauty of this solution very fast production, and never processors gets down.

Comment: The trouble you're going to have is that you cannot get the software (essentially an IDE and compiler) for these platforms unless you are a _dealer_ for the company.  As an end user, you would not be able to get the software, and so would be unable to use it.  It would probably be possible to get the GCC target, but without knowing more about the platform you'd probably have little luck actually programming and running the system.

Comment: Extron now has a programming IDE / environment called 'Global Scripter' that utilizes parts of the Python language (some libraries are restricted / jailed).